# If there are "arbitrarily efficient" paths in a given direction, is there always a "best" path in that direction?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

$\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}$
$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}$
$\newcommand{\be}{\beta}$

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, $S \subset M,p \in M \setminus{S}$, and $v \in T_pM$ be a unit vector. Let $d_S$ be the distance function from $S$.

> Suppose that for every unit speed path $\be(t)$ starting at $p$, there exists $\ep_{\beta}>0$ and a unit speed path $\al_{\beta}:(-\ep_{\beta},\ep_{\beta}) \to M$ also starting at $p$, such that $\dot \al_{\beta}(0) = v$ and
>   $$
> d_S(\al_{\beta}(t)) \le  d_S(\be(t)) \quad \text{ for all } t \in (-\ep_{\beta},\ep_{\beta}).
> $$

Does there exist a single unit speed path $\al:(-\ep,\ep) \to M$ starting at $p$ with velocity $v$, that "beats" all the different $\beta$'s at once?

i.e. I want $\al(0)=p , \dot \al(0) = v,$ such that for every
unit speed path $\be(t)$ starting at $p$,
$$
d_S(\al(t)) \le  d_S(\be(t)) \quad \text{ for all } t \in \left( -\tilde \ep_{\beta},\tilde \ep_{\beta}  \right).
$$

(I allow $\tilde \ep_{\beta} <  \ep_{\beta}$.) Informally, I am assuming that $v$ is a "*preferred direction of movement towards $S$ from $p$*", and I ask if there is a single path in that direction, which beats all other paths for short times. My guess is that the geodesic $t \to \exp_p(tv)$ should do the job, but I am not sure how to prove that.

Comment: Consider $M = \Bbb R^2, S = 0\times \Bbb R, p = (1,0), v = (1,0)$ and $\beta(t) = (1 + t, 0)$. Paths improve the quicker they turn around, but the limit of that is a path that immediately reverses, which will not have $v$ as its initial tangent.

Comment: Thank you, but your construction does not satisfy my assumptions. Not *every* path $\beta$ can be "beaten" by a path with initial velocity $v$. (The path $t \to (1-t,0)$ is the unique minimizing geodesic, and it strictly beats all other paths. In particular, no path with velocity $v=(1,0)$ can beat it, even for a short time (The point is that I required that paths with velocity $v$ will beat *all paths*, not just paths with initial velocity $v$).

Comment: However, I think you did make a very nice and interesting observation: If you *fix* a specific initial velocity vector, then within the class of all paths with this  initial velocity, we don't always have a "best" path. (because, as you said, we can always turn around quicker and quicker....).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $M$ is complete, choose a sequence $x_i \in S$ for which $d(p,x_i)$ approaches $D = \text{inf}\{d(p,x) \mid x \in S\}$.

It follows that the set $Q = \{q \in \overline D \mid d(p,q)=D\}$ is not empty. The property of your vector $v$ that you state will be true if and only if $v$ is the initial direction of some unit speed geodesic $\alpha$ from $p$ to some $q \in Q$.

The point is that if $\alpha$ does have that form then $d_S(\alpha(t)) = D-t$, and $d_S(\beta(t)) \ge D-t$ for each of your $\beta$ paths.

If on the other hand if $\alpha$ does not have that form then you can take $\beta$ to be a path which *does* have that form.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is positive. Since for every unit speed path starting from $p$ at time $t=0$, we always have $d_S(\alpha(t)) \ge d_S(p)-t$ for every $t$, and since we [there always exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3156860/104576) an "optimal" unit speed path $\alpha(t)$, satisfying $d_S(\alpha(t)) = d_S(p)-t$ for sufficiently small $t$, a path that beats (weakly) this optimal path,  must be optimal itself. So, we can take as a challenge $\beta:=$ an "optimal path"-and conclude that there exist an optimal path in the $v$ direction, as required.